# Combine f-string and raw string literal

Tags: python, python-3.x, f-string

I'm wondering how to use an f-string whilst using `r` to get a raw string literal. I currently have it as below but would like the option of allowing any name to replace `Alex` I was thinking adding an f-string and then replacing `Alex` with curly braces and putting username inside but this doesn't work with the `r`.

```
username = input('Enter name')
download_folder = r'C:\Users\Alex\Downloads'
```

Comment: you can use `print("{0}".format(variable))`.

Comment: "...but this doesn't work with the r". Why? Which error do you get? What is the code that you are trying?

Comment: Even though raw string literals fix the problem of escaping the backslashes, specifically for creating a path it's preferred to use forward slashes anyway; see [How should I write a Windows path in a Python string literal?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2953834).

Answer (score 242, accepted):

You can combine the `f` for an f-string with the `r` for a raw string:

```
user = 'Alex'
dirToSee = fr'C:\Users\{user}\Downloads'
print (dirToSee) # prints C:\Users\Alex\Downloads
```

The `r` only disables backslash escape sequence processing, not f-string processing.

Quoting the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#string-and-bytes-literals):

> The 'f' may be combined with 'r', but not with 'b' or 'u', therefore raw formatted strings are possible, but formatted bytes literals are not.
>
> ...
>
> Unless an 'r' or 'R' prefix is present, escape sequences in string and bytes literals are interpreted...

Comment: Ahh great thank you. I tried doing it rf but didn't work.

Comment: @lammyalex `rf` should also work. See [String and Bytes literals](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#string-and-bytes-literals)

Comment: when using `fr` PyCharm IDE shows an error but when you run the code, it works without any issue.

Comment: For me, that's a warning, not an error: it is not backward compatible with earlier versions of Python. It will run fine for Python 3.6 and later.

Comment: f-strings are already not supported in 3.5 and below, so it's not as if using `rf` or `fr` as a prefix causes a special compatibility problem.

Comment: When combining both, just be mindful that `{}` won't be 'raw' any more.  This is annoying for regex patterns: `r'{user}\w+{4}'` will not be `'Alex\w+{4}'` but `'Alex\w+4'`! Of course, fix is simple: `f'{user}'r'\w+{4}'`

Comment: @user2357112, what about expression like this `f"User(id={self.id!r}"`. what does it the `!r` mean?

Comment: @CholthiPaulTtiopic Please remove your comment as it does not apply to this question. You may want to ask a new question rather than post here. (This may help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1436703/what-is-the-difference-between-str-and-repr and the !r is how the user asks for repr.)

Answer (score 19):

Alternatively, you could use the `str.format()` method.

```
name = input("What is your name? ")
print(r"C:\Users\{name}\Downloads".format(name=name))
```

This will format the raw string by inserting the `name` value.

Comment: I think this is a great alternative solution! Thanks for adding this.

Answer (score 5):

As others have mentioned, it's indeed possible to mix `r` and `f`.
Be careful, though, since the interpolated strings will not be raw by default:

```
not_escaped = "\not_escaped"
half_escaped = rf"escaped_{not_escaped}"

print(half_escaped)
### outputs:
# escaped_
# ot_escaped
```

You'd have to use `r` for the interpolated strings too:

```
escaped = r"\n_escaped"
full_escaped = rf"escaped_too_{escaped}"

print(full_escaped)
# escaped_too_\n_escaped
```

Answer (score 2):

Since you are working with file paths, I would avoid f-strings and rather use a library geared for path manipulation. For example [`pathlib`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html) would allow you to do:

```
from pathlib import Path
username = input('Enter name')
download_folder = Path('C:/Users', username, 'Downloads')
```

This approach also offers some other common file operations such as, such as [`is_dir`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html#pathlib.Path.is_dir) [`open`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html#pathlib.Path.open).

Alternatively you could also use [`os.path.join`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html#os.path.join))

Comment: Good to know, I never noticed it's possible to specify multiple parameters for `Path(...)`

Comment: Yes, it is also equivalent to `Path('C:/Users') / username / 'Downloads'`

Answer (score 2):

The simplest way I've found of doing this is to use implicit line continuation to split my strings up into component parts, i.e. separate out 'r' and 'f' strings inside parenthases. Here's an example matplotlib title with 'normal', 'formatted', and 'raw' string literals ([read more here](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#literals)):

```
plt.title('Blind Surveys 01-FEB-2022\n'
         f'Recording{n}; Mean dose rate: {m.get_mean_doserate()*1000:.4f}'
         r' $\mathrm{\mu}$Sv/hr', fontsize='x-large')
```

[image]

Just to make it more applicable to the question, you can also use implicit line continuation in variable declaration:

```
user = ‘Alex’
dir_out = (r‘C:\Users\’
           f‘{user}’
           r‘\Downloads’)
print(dir_out) #C:\Users\Alex\Downloads
```

Admittedly this seems a bit overkill for this simple scenario but will be your friend when strings become more complex!

Comment: Interesting. The last example looks nice and readable. Yet another alternative would be to use pathlib and let it join paths with `/`.

Answer (score -3):

you can try:

```
username = input('Enter name')
download_folder = r'C:\Users\Alex\Downloads'
download_folder = download_folder.replace("Alex", username)
print(download_folder)
```