# Combining f-string with raw string to be used inside regex gives SyntaxError; ValueError or wrong result

Tags: python, python-3.x, regex, python-3.7, f-string

I have a string here :

```
s0 = 'Ready1   Origin1                 Destination1             Type1       Rate1      Phone1 #     Pro1 #'
```

and the following variable being calculated like this :

```
is_head = len([i.group() for i in re.finditer(r"(\s+){2,}", s0)]) >= 3
```

which gives me `True` which is right and expected result for me. Now I have another variable `cont_` which might hold any value between `2` to `6`. I want to change the regex from `r"(\s+){2,}"` to `r"(\s+){6,}"` based on value of `cont_`. I want to get the variable `is_head` without declaring separate regex for each cases. For this I need to use f-string along with raw string which is currently being used for regex checking. I've tried these :

```
>>> len([i.group() for i in re.finditer(fr"(\s+){{cont_},}", s0)]) >= 3
  File "<stdin>", line 1
SyntaxError: f-string: single '}' is not allowed
>>> len([i.group() for i in re.finditer(rf"(\s+){{cont_},}", s0)]) >= 3
  File "<stdin>", line 1
SyntaxError: f-string: single '}' is not allowed
```

As shown, both gives `SyntaxError`. I've also tried the following with `.format()` :

```
>>> len([i.group() for i in re.finditer(r"(\s+){{con},}".format(cont_), s0)]) >= 3
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ValueError: Single '}' encountered in format string
>>> len([i.group() for i in re.finditer(r"(\s+){{0},}".format(cont_), s0)]) >= 3
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ValueError: Single '}' encountered in format string
```

in that case I get `ValueError`. Now I've also tried these :

```
>>> len([i.group() for i in re.finditer(fr"(\s+){cont_,}", s0)]) >= 3
False
>>> len([i.group() for i in re.finditer(rf"(\s+){cont_,}", s0)]) >= 3
False
```

These don't produce any error but give wrong result in each case. If I run with `cont_ = 2` case, `is_head` would have been set `True`. Upon further inspection, I can see that `rf"(\s+){cont_,}"` as well as `fr"(\s+){cont_,}"` - both are equivalent to `'(\\s+)(2,)'` which shouldn't be the proper regex. How to overcome this without explicitly having separate regexes for each possible values of `cont_` variable and thereafter using that regex.

**NOTE** : Please notice, I'm aware that a similar question like this had been asked before [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58302531/combine-f-string-and-raw-string-literal). But the solutions there are of no help for my cause.

Comment: `(\s+){2,}` makes little sense, you probably wanted to match chunks of two or more whitespaces with `\s{2,}`. Thus, you need `rf"\s{{{cont_},}}"`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `(\s+){2,}` pattern matches *one or more* whitespaces *two or more times*, which makes little sense. Chunks of two or more whitespaces are matched with `\s{2,}`.

Next, in f-strings or format strings, literal curly braces must be doubled.

Thus, you need

```
rf"\s{{{cont_},}}"
```

where the first `{{` is a literal `{`, `{cont_}` stands for the `cont_` value and `}}` at the end is a literal `}` char.